# Github pages : Page build failed, #troubleshooting-build-errors

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages, github-for-windows

I received the e-mail that 'Page build failure' from Github.

> The page build failed for the `master` branch with the following error:
>
> Page build failed. For more information, see https://help.github.com/en/articles/troubleshooting-> 
>        jekyll-build-errors-for-github-pages-sites#troubleshooting-build-errors.
>
> For information on troubleshooting Jekyll see:
>
> https://help.github.com/articles/troubleshooting-jekyll-builds
>
> If you have any questions you can contact us by replying to this email.

I tried to some of things but i don't know how to fixed it..

we used 'index.md' and '_config.yml' for publishing. 
It was run but suddenly it doesn't working.
so if i change the 'index.md' it doesn't updating in github-page..
I want to stop seeing that sentence 'page build failed' in the commit.

if you want to see our github then here is. https://github.com/kookmin-sw/2019-cap1-2019_10

All help appreciated! Thanks, all.

Comment: I cloned your repo and got errors related to Gem versions. I was able to get it to build after adding the `github-pages` Gem to a Gemfile and running `bundle update` and then forcing the versions with `bundle exec`.

Comment: [SOLVED] Some branch had an error file, so it had page failed.